# Generate array of function references in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a lot of functions starting with a given prefix. I would like to create an array of these functions and then execute them one by one.

Consider:

```
use v5.12;

my @names = qw(a b);
my @ss = map { "s".$_ } @names;

sub sa {
    say "a";
}

sub sb {
    say "b";
}
```

Here the function prefix is `s`. How do I call these functions one by one, for instance, using a `for` loop..? (I tried inserting a `\&` inside the `map` command, but that did not work.)

Note that all the functions will take the same arguments, and that's why I think this is something that could be useful to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
use 5.012;

my @names = qw(a b);
my @ss    = map { \&{"s$_"} } @names;

sub sa {
    say "a";
}

sub sb {
    say "b";
}

&$_() for @ss;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/144406). In short, references to the functions are stored. Note that storing subroutine names in `@ss` and calling those (with `&` sygil) fails in the strict mode:

> Can't use string ("sa") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs"

And, perhaps it's just me, but I'd rather define these functions in a hash:

```
my %hof = (
  a => sub { say 'a'; },
  b => sub { say 'b'; },
  c => sub { say 'c: ' . $_[0]; },
);

$hof{$_}('something') for sort keys %hof;
```

**output**

```
a
b
c: something
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.12;

use Data::Dumper;

my @names = qw(a b);
my @ss = map { $main::{"s$_"} } @names;

$_->() for @ss;


sub sa {
    say "a";
}

sub sb {
    say "b";
}
```